# Uncommenting generate_messages(...) breaks import of (non-ROS) Python module

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yesterday I created the first custom message for my ROS package, and it broke a Python import that I was using:

```
from oars_gb.libraries.dynamixels.dynamixel_controller import DynamixelController
```

Yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kyle/oars/catkin_ws/src/trans-atlantic-sailboat/oars_gb/nodes/acting/motor_controller.py", line 4, in <module>
    from oars_gb.libraries.dynamixels.dynamixel_motor import DynamixelMotor
ImportError: No module named libraries.dynamixels.dynamixel_motor
```

To me, it seems as though it's finding the `oars_gb` module (my ROS package), but not the submodules...

I traced it down to uncommenting `generate_messages(...)` in CMakeLists.txt:

```
## UNCOMMENTING THIS (LIKE IT IS NOW) BREAKS THE IMPORT
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
#  geometry_msgs
#  sensor_msgs
)
```

I can still import the module by running `from oars_gb.libraries.dynamixels.dynamixel_motor import DynamixelMotor` in a Python interpreter (with `PYTHONPATH` set accordingly, as it should be for ROS).

Also, I don't know if this helps to provide any clues, but commenting out `generate_messages(...)` after I've broken it and rerunning `catkin_make` isn't enough to fix the problem. I have to delete `catkin_ws/devel` and then run `catkin_make` again.

The full repo is available [here](https://github.com/olin-robotic-sailing/trans-atlantic-sailboat/tree/custom-msg-breaking).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283474/uncommenting-generate_messages(...)-breaks-import-of-(non-ros)-python-module/) by [mightimaus](https://answers.ros.org/users/30283/mightimaus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I determined the problem was that the Python module name (`oars_gb`, the name of the folder in my repo) was conflicting with the ROS package name. When I uncommented `generate_messages(...)`, it generated a Python module in `devel/oars_gb` with my custom message, which is where it then started looking for the `libraries` folder as well.

To fix it, I renamed the folder in my repo to `oars_gb_pkg`.

---

Originally posted by [mightimaus](https://answers.ros.org/users/30283/mightimaus/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0